# dbus: flush connection?

Tags: c, linux, dbus

When I do a "dbus_connection_close", do I need to flush the message queue?

In other words, do I need to continue with "dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch" until I receive the "disconnected" indication or is it safe to stop dispatching?

**Updated:** I need to close the connection to DBus in a clean manner. From reading the documentation, all the clean-up must be done prior to "unreferencing" the connection and this process isn't very well documented IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging, it appears that there are two types of connection: shared and private.

The shared connection **mustn't** be closed just *unreferenced*. Furthermore, it does not appear that the connection must be flushed & dispatched **unless** the outgoing messages must be delivered.

In my case, I just needed to end the communication over DBus as soon as possible without trying to salvage any outgoing messages.

Thus the short answer is: NO - no flushing / no dispatching needs to be done prior to `dbus_connection_unref`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [at the documentation for dbus_connection_close()](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html#g906ba87d4d85ba26da9bd412629805d4), the only thing that [may be invoked](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html#gaf9309c87a47bb54c1d6d01366fb757b) is the dispatch status function to indicate that the connection has been closed.

So, ordering here is something you probably want to pay attention to .. i.e getting notified of a closed / dropped connection prior to things left in the message queue.

Looking at the [source of the function](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/dbus-connection_8c-source.html#l02741), it looks like the only thing its going to do is return if fail, i.e. invalid connection / NULL pointer. Otherwise, it (seems) to just hang up.

This means yes, you probably should flush the message queue prior to hanging up.

**Disclaimer**: I've only had to talk to dbus a few times, I'm not by any means an authority on it.

Comment: My problem is actually the other way around: I need to close the connection to DBus and make sure I perform the necessary cleanup.

Comment: @jldupont: Then yes, you should flush the message queue. I'll edit my answer to be more obvious.